# smoke fire alarm circuit and relay SPDT

Tags: sensor, smoke-sensor

I want to put relay SPDT in the output of the below circuit to connect with circuit working in 12v.

when the buzzer run the relay switch on or off to another circuit automatically

I want to run it in mulitsim  also if some one can explain in details the circuit how it is working and the use of each components I the circuit

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This (*[original source is here](http://www.electroschematics.com/5450/smart-smoke-sensor-alarm/)*) with some "explanation".

This is a pretty dubious circuit in general and I really doubt an ordinary non-differental photo interruptor  will work satisfactorily as a smoke detector at non-lethal smoke densities. If you crank P2 down all the way it will burn out T2. It depends on leakage to keep T4 off. There are other issues.

Modern smoke detectors usually use a sensitive ionization chamber with a tiny bit of [Americium-241](http://www.world-nuclear.org/info/non-power-nuclear-applications/radioisotopes/smoke-detectors-and-americium/) radioactive material. Ones that operate photoelectrically usually use a [scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_detector#Optical) principle. The method suggested here ([beam detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_beam_smoke_detector)) is prone to all sorts of problems.

If you want to use it as a beam break detector, you could try connecting another MOSFET gate to the one driving the buzzer and using that to switch a relay (diode across the coil). But I'd suggest staying away.. this is strictly amateur hour stuff.